# Blockchain Forking, is it a threat?

Tags: ether, contract-design

I am starting to work on the ethereum blockchain, and i had some thoughts about forking blockchains. i want to know more about forking and its consequences, and how to actually detect any fork attempt.

**EDIT** 
what i mean about fork in this context is the fact of starting an other blockchain starting from a certain block. what i think it does is bypass the data stored in the blocks after the one the fork started with.

Comment: Hi there. Can you clarify what you mean by a "fork" in the context you're referring to?

Comment: What is your definition of "threat"? Sometimes a fork can be a good thing if you want to fix a bug or a defficiency. But that can be subjective in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blockchain forking is a thread only if there is a community that supports the fork. If a fork happens but there's nobody mining on it, trying to build competing dApps it's not a threat.

So instead of checking for forks (which actually happen, but reach consensus quickly, thus neutralizing the fork) it's more important to be aware of people's opinion forking, having a different point of view on how Ethereum's development should evolve. If there is a big enough group of people who think Ethereum should evolve in a different manner, a fork could happen (i.e. ETC / ETH fork, aka Dao Hack)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how much of a threat it is, but there has been research suggesting it's possible.  I'm going to link here to a blog post that mentions the formal academic research and tries to dismiss it, on the grounds that miners are altruistic.  But this post was a while back, before mining became such a huge deal because of the monetary benefit of success, and I wonder if it still holds true.

https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/selfish-mining-a-25-attack-against-the-bitcoin-network-1383578440/